# Post Author ID in wordpress permalinks settings

Tags: wordpress

I am making my custom permalinks and want to get the post author id in it I have tried many things but all in vain, Please help me on this one.

Comment: where is your code which one you tried?

Comment: I have not tried any code I am making the permalink from the wordpress permalink setting and i want to get post author id there

Comment: ok so if someone clicks on your blog post the author id must be included in the URL right?

Comment: yes my url should look like this
/i/productID/AuthorID

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1** add this into your functions.php

Guidance here
 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112719/how-to-use-author-id-in-post-permalink

```
function wpse_112719_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%author%' ) !== false ) {
        $authordata = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $author_id = $authordata->ID;
        $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', $author_id, $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wpse_112719_pre_post_link', 10, 3 );

function wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "([0-9]+)/(.*)",
        'index.php?name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

**STEP 2** login to admin end and set the permalinks **Custom Structure** some thing like this : /%postname%/%author%

Comment: It's like this ( http://localhost/youroegirl/i/1286/adeline-1/ ) now i just want to add the author ID after the product ID

Comment: just add permalinks /%postname%/%author% into the custom structure and then check it on your blog post single page page

Comment: After adding the link become ( http://localhost/youroegirl/i/%postname%/%author%/l/ )

Comment: send screenshot of your permalinks from admin end

Comment: LOL this is for products url not WordPress blog post url you mentioning in the image.

Comment: Yes is it possible

Comment: Please compare both screenshots the author field must be there into products  https://prnt.sc/haq3sz  here is wp post or pages types  https://prnt.sc/haq3j6

Comment: I don't have author name on product tab on admin side

Comment: Yes got it that's the problem  look at screenshot this is for for WordPress permalinks https://prnt.sc/haq5si not for products links

Comment: But I want it for woo commerece products

Comment: OK then first add author for your products

Comment: Author Id are there in the database I have checked it